# Nativescript Keep Keyboard Shown After Enter Press - Android

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard, nativescript

I am trying to build a chat view in Nativescript Javascript. I have it so the "Send" button on the keyboard is pressed and sends the message.

I am using the below code to keep the keyboard open, however, I have a weird behavior whereby the first 'enter' button press on the keyboard isn't registered, and I have to click it again to send the first message.

Its only on the first message, so I have to do a double click, and from that point on it works as normal, sending single messages with each click and constantly showing the keyboard.

I have an issue whereby I have the following code:

```
const page = args.object;
testingText = page.getViewById("chatText");
testingText.focus();

if(testingText.android)
{
    console.log("PAST IF");
    testingText.android.setOnEditorActionListener(new 
                  android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener({
        onEditorAction: function (callbackType, result){

            console.log("PAST IF");
            if(result==android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
                console.log("WORKING");
                console.log("CALL BACK " + callbackType)
            }
            console.log("CALL BACK " + callbackType);
            return true;
        }
    }));
    console.log("CALL BACK ");
}
```

Any help would be great, I'm lost as to why it does this.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript core modules covers the most for you so you don't have to write native code for everything except in special cases. That's being said, you have [returnPress](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield#returnpressevent) event which is fired when the return key (enter or send button based on your [returnKeyType](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield#returnkeytype)) which you can listen to and send your message.